# Docker how to run node js

Tags: php, node.js, docker

This is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.9'

networks:
  bedrock:

services:
  web:
    container_name: kawa-web
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html:delegated
      - ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql
    networks:
      - bedrock

  php:
    container_name: kawa-php
    image: nanoninja/php-fpm:8.0
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
      - ./docker/config/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
    networks:
      - bedrock

  mysql:
    container_name: kawa-db
    image: mysql:8
    volumes:
      - ./docker/db:/var/lib/mysql:delegated
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
    networks:
      - bedrock

  node:
    container_name: kawa-node
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: node.dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - bedrock
```

Content of `node.dockerfile`

```
FROM node:18-alpine

WORKDIR /var/www/html

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080
```

When I run `docker compose up -d` it shows

```
failed to solve: error from sender: open /path/to/project/docker/db/#innodb_temp: permission denied
```

How can I fix this? Or any another way to run nodejs inside PHP container maybe?

Comment: Why is this tagged with PHP?

Comment: Can you reduce the Compose setup to a [mcve]?  With this setup it looks like you're `COPY`ing your MySQL data directory into the Node image, which shouldn't be necessary; does it help to refactor your source tree so the JavaScript code, PHP code, static assets, and database storage are in separate non-overlapping directories?

Comment: @DavidMaze I need them all - it kinda like Laravel setup. But even when I remove all services but `node` it still showing this error - not sure even why. I've edited and remove some non-related services

Comment: @DavidMaze ah yeah you were right - I'm copying mysql data. It still not running, I cannot see this container in `docker ps` but that out of scope of this question. You may provide an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your Compose setup has:

```yaml
services:
  mysql:
    volumes:
      - ./docker/db:/var/lib/mysql:delegated
  node:
    build:
      context: .
```

The MySQL data directory is in the `./docker/db` directory.  That's inside the `.` build-context directory of the Node application, so `docker-compose build` among other things sends the entire MySQL data to itself, and if the database is currently running, you could get lock or permission problems like this.

The best approach to work around this is to split your application into separate directories, and have each language component only build its own subdirectory.

```
$ ls -1F
data/
docker-compose.yml
js/
php/
static/

$ ls -1F js
Dockerfile
index.js
node_modules/
package.json
package-lock.json
```

```yaml
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'
services:
  ...
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/mysql:delegated
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
  node:
    build: ./js
```

(Note that I've used the short syntax for `build:` to use the default `Dockerfile` in the context directory; I've removed unnecessary `container_name:` and `networks:` options, using the Compose-provided `default` network; and I've removed the `volumes:` that overwrite the image's content.  Make sure `./js/Dockerfile` has a `CMD` instruction that says how to start the container.)